# Como habilitar el PREVIEW de xamarin.forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

disculpe lo absurdo de mi pregunta, es que no encuentro como habilitar el Preview de **xamarin.forms** en mi **visual studio 2019** he buscado en internet, pero ninguno me sirve. Ya probé reinstalando el visual, pero aún así este problema persiste, adjuto fotos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que quiero ver, pero no me sale la barra lateral en la cual se le da click para que genere la preview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso que esta remarcado en rojo no me sale y no se como configurarlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente la PREVIEW en el diseñador se ha ido deshabilitando porque según entiendo se está priorizando el uso del **HOT RELOAD** o **RECARGA ACTIVA** que consiste en ejecutar el proyecto y -al iniciarse el emulador- hacer los cambios y darle SAVE y esos cambios se transmiten al emulador en tiempo de ejecución, entonces la PREVIEW se hace directo en la pantalla del emulador.

En mi caso la PREVIEW se deshabilitó sola sin preguntarme, pero puedes modificar este comportamiento desde Visual Studio eligiendo si quieres usar la recarga activa o no, para habilitarla, en el caso de Windows, active la casilla Habilitar recarga activa de XAML (y las plataformas necesarias) en:

**herramientas** > **Opciones** > **depurar** > **recargas activas**.

En versiones anteriores de Visual Studio 2019, la casilla se encuentra en **herramientas** > **Opciones de** > > **recarga en caliente de Xamarin**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para deshabilitarla es el proceso inverso.

Puedes encontrar más información al respeto en la documentación oficial de Xamarin.
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload

Comment: Gracias amigo1 al menos ya tengo una respuesta fija.